# Are there common problems between rounting and mat-dialogs in Angular?

Tags: routing

What I wanted to do was to open a mat-dialog by clicking on an icon.
This mat-dialog is a split panel that has to the left side buttons that can be clicked and to the right side a content space where other components are supposed to be loaded on click on the specific button. 
Now, I followed the guidelines of the original documentation for routing on https://angular.io/guide/router , but when I clicked the first icon to open the dialog, it's style was changed and it didn't open in form of a dialog anymore. Now I figured I could just keep the dialog style by changing the url within the method of calling the dialog like this

```
dialogRef.afterOpened().subscribe(result => {
      this.router.navigate(['/dialog']);
    });
   dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
     this.router.navigate(['']);
    });
```

Like this the url changed with opening anf closing the dialog the way I wanted. But I've got another routing-module with another component, which is working perfectly fine, before opening the dialog,but does not work anymore afterwards.
And now the loading of the component via routing and using `<router-outlet>` in the html tag does not work either. 
Now, my question is if there are some general problems with mat-dialog and routing that I might solve by using a different way? Is it necassary to code a custom dialog (not using mat-dialog)? I had everything working fine before with a service, though I thought changing the url and opening the components by navigation would be a lot less code and a nicer solution.

Hopefully, someone can explain this problem to me and what is actually happening. I might provide more general code, but like I said I pretty much followed the official documentation.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please review the tag you've applied to this question. I believe it is not an appropriate tag for this question, and people looking for questions about Angular will not find this question based on that tag.